# Is there a method or a way to shuffle/return variations of a string utilising javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, shuffle

So I am trying to shuffle the input of a user

e.g

User inputs "123HDJ"

I extract/match the numbers from the string

and I return 213 123 321 132 ...

So far I have only been able to return the numbers that occur from user input i.e 123

Again I am a newbie so nothing too overcomplicated

This is currently what I have

```
  solution () {
    let input = document.getElementById("number").value;

  if (input.length > 0 ){

    const numbers = /[0-9]/g;

    let newInput = input.match(numbers).join("");

    let shuffled = newInput
    
      console.log(typeof newInput)
      alert(newInput)
    
  }
  
  else {
      console.log("Error please try again"); 
  
  }
  }
```

I am not looking to change my any code above `let shuffled` as I want my code to remain as organically mine as possible lol

please help if you can

Comment: This should help: [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9960908/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling I have taken a brief look and I am just wondering if there was anything simpler than that

Comment: What do you consider simple? Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/30551462/218196 simple?

Comment: Simpler but maybe because I'm still learning still looks a bit complex